# Minimize the surface area of a $3$-dimensional object consisting of a ball on top of a truncated cone

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Suppose I want to produce some special objects consisting of a ball with a truncated cone as bottom (the ball is placed on top of the truncated cone).

The whole object has a volume of $325$ $\text{cm}^3$. The bottom of the truncated cone and the ball has the same diameter. The top of the truncated cone has a diameter that is $2 \ \text{cm}$  less then the bottom of it.

Now, I want to find the diameter and the height producing the smallest possible surface area.

[image]

Let $R_1$ denote the volume of the ball and $R_2$ the volume of the truncated cone. Then $$R_1 + R_2 = \underbrace{\frac 4 3  \cdot \pi \cdot (\frac d 2)^3}_{\text {volume of the ball}} + \underbrace{\frac 1 3  \cdot \pi \cdot h \cdot ((\frac {d-2} 2)^2 + (\frac d 2)^2 + \frac {d-2}  2 \cdot  \frac d 2)}_{\text {volume of the truncated cone}} = 325  \ \text {cm}^3$$

and $d, h \ge 0$ (right ?)

Then the objective is the minimize the surfacearea of this object, but how is this accomplished ?

I've computed the surface area function $A(d,h) = \underbrace {4 \cdot \pi \cdot (\frac d 2)^2}_{\text {surfacearea of the ball}} + \underbrace{\pi \cdot (\frac {d-2} 2 + \frac d 2) \cdot \sqrt {h^2 + (\frac d 2 - \frac {d-2} 2)^2}}_{\text {surfacearea of the truncacated cone}}$

Comment: What about the volume of the spherical cap that is counted twice?

Comment: No, it is not :-)

Comment: What about the top and bottom of the cone?

Answer (score 0):

Simplify first the area function to

$$
A(d,h)=\pi d^2+\pi (d-1)\sqrt{h^2+1}
$$

Put $h$ as a function of $d$ using the equation for the volumes, so

$$
h=
\frac{325-\frac{4}{3}\pi\big(\frac{d}{2}\big)^3}{\frac{1}{3}\pi\Big(\big(\frac{d-2}{2}\big)^2+\big(\frac{d}{2}\big)^2+\frac{d-2}{2}\frac{d}{2}\Big)}
=\frac{\frac{3900}{\pi}-2d^3}{3d^2-6d+4}
$$

If you want

$$
h(d)
=\frac{\frac{3900}{\pi}-2d^3}{3d^2-6d+4}
$$

Now the area function only depends on $d$

$$
A(d,h(d))=A(d)=\pi d^2+\pi (d-1)\sqrt{h(d)^2+1}
$$

As the area only depends on $d$, one can only derivate with respect to $d$

$$
A'(d)=2\pi d+\pi\bigg(1\cdot\sqrt{h(d)^2+1}+(d-1)\frac{h(d)h'(d)}{\sqrt{h(d)^2+1}}\bigg)
$$

Now solve $A'(d)=0$ (good luck with that!)

(Hint: maybe at this point you will be allowed to use computers)

(Hint 2: a $\pi$ cancels, perhaps something else can be done to simplify)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use the radius $r$ instead of diameter $d$ as a variable.

Constraint:
$$V(r, h) = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 + \frac{1}{3}\pi h (3r^2 - 3r + 1) $$

Function to be minimized:
$$A(r, h) = 4\pi r^2 + (2r + 1)\sqrt{h^2 + 1} $$

This can be solved using Lagrange multipliers

$$
\left\{ \begin{matrix} 
\frac{\partial A}{\partial r} = \lambda \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial A}{\partial h} = \lambda \frac{\partial V}{\partial h} \\
V = 325
\end{matrix} \right. \Rightarrow
\left\{ \begin{matrix} 
8\pi r + 2\sqrt{h^2+1} = \lambda \big(4\pi r^2 + \pi h (2r - 1) \big) \\
(2r+1) \frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+1}} = \lambda \frac{1}{3}\pi (3r^2 - 3r + 1) \\
\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 + \frac{1}{3}\pi h (3r^2 - 3r + 1) = 325
\end{matrix} \right. 
$$

What you get now is a system of equations in $r, h, \lambda$ that you can solve